# Using XRay on Jira Cloud version?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to configure XRAY on our *cloud* Jira instance, so I can click on "Create" up on top and have my Xray fields available to set right there.
However, I am finding that custom fields created by Xray are not available for Screens or Input forms on Jira.

Is there a way to overcome this? What could I be doing wrong?
Else, is there a way to copy the content of one of my custom fields to the x-ray fields?
How has the rest of the community tackled this problem?